# Put element above element in parent RelativLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-relativelayout

I want to put element TextView "singleName" above ViewPager on parent RelativeLayout, is it possible or not?

here xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/singleScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/indicatorWrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/singleName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_height" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/singleSlider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_height"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestin ?

Comment: do you need the NestedScrollView?

have you tried `layout_above` or `layout_below`?

Comment: @peshkira yes I need scrollview, and layout_above doesn't work for parent RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/singleSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_height"
        android:alignParentBottom="true"
    />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/singleScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/singleSlider"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/indicatorWrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/singleName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_height" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This should put the viewpager at the bottom of the screen and the nested scroll layout should fill in the rest of the screen above.

Answer (score -1):

try adding this to your ViewPager:

```
android:layout_below="@id/singleScroll"
```